# undefined reference to symbol 'TIFFOpen@@LIBTIFF_4.0'

Tags: c++, codeblocks, wxwidgets

Trying to build a wxWiget project I get the error: "undefined reference to symbol 'TIFFOpen@@LIBTIFF_4.0' ".
System: Ubuntu 15.02
Code::Blocks

-------------- Build: Debug in wx092404 (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

g++  -o bin/Debug/wx092404 obj/Debug/librjmcmc-master/samples/building_footprint_rectangle/gui/building_footprint_rectangle_gui.o 
-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -pthread -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro  -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu   -lwx_gtk2u_richtext-2.8 -lwx_gtk2u_aui-2.8 -lwx_gtk2u_xrc-2.8 -lwx_gtk2u_qa-2.8 -lwx_gtk2u_html-2.8 -lwx_gtk2u_adv-2.8 -lwx_gtk2u_core-2.8 -lwx_baseu_xml-2.8 -lwx_baseu_net-2.8 -lwx_baseu-2.8
/usr/bin/ld: obj/Debug/librjmcmc-master/samples/building_footprint_rectangle/gui/building_footprint_rectangle_gui.o: undefined reference to symbol 'TIFFOpen@@LIBTIFF_4.0'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so.5: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))

Comment: Sorry I am  a novice,I will improve the quality of question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `-ltiff` to your linker command, to link against `libtiff`.